# pandas series isdigit() function gives NaN

Tags: pandas, nan

I am using the isdigit function in Pandas series. It give me NaN values even when the series has integers in it. What could possibly be wrong here.

Comment: Please provide the code so others can verify and explain why

Comment: isdigit is for a string.  What is your data type?

Comment: df=employee.areacode.str.isdigit()

Comment: the dtype of the series is object - some elements have been stored as long integers and some as alphanumeric. I am converting the integers into string before performing the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first convert column `areacode` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then use [`isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html):

```
employee = pd.DataFrame({'areacode':pd.Series([204,200,'AAA','BBB'])})
print employee
  areacode
0      204
1      200
2      AAA
3      BBB

employee['areacode'] = employee['areacode'].astype(str)
print employee.areacode.str.isdigit()
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: areacode, dtype: bool
```

Without converting get `NaN` values:

```
employee = pd.DataFrame({'areacode':pd.Series([204,200,'AAA','BBB'])})

print employee.areacode.str.isdigit()
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    False
3    False
Name: areacode, dtype: object
```